# Nginx: Location only if method matches

Tags: nginx, methods, proxy, config, http-method

I'm trying to configure a location block which only matches on a specific location AND method. More precisely: static HTML for all locations, and PHP for a single POST location.

- GET / -> @static
- POST / -> @static
- ANY /any-path -> @static
- ANY /specific -> @static
- POST /specific -> @php

Can I break out of a location block and let the next match? Like a continue in a loop.

Have been through quite a bit, but not even an approach. That's why such a weird config, since it's different applications in the back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a chain of [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) blocks:

```
map $special_route$request_method $loc {
    1POST      php;
    default    static;
}
map $uri $special_route {
    /specific  1;
    # default value will be an empty string
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        try_files /dev/null @$loc;
    }
    location @static {
        # static location
        ...
    }
    location @php {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        # always use hard coded script filename for this specific POST request
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/path/to/your/script.php;
        # pass the request to the FastCGI backend
        fastcgi_pass unix:<socket_file_name>;
    }
}
```